# A tutorial on Lexical parser

Tags: scala, scanning, parser-combinators, combinators

I am a bit stuck with parser combinators on whitespaces. They consume keyword even if keyword is a prefix in the "keywordandtherestofthestream". Moreover, `identifier = rep1("a")` consumes both letters in `a a` as single `aa`. The pieces of information suggest that I need to do some lexing and it is possible to stack the parser combinator on top of the lexer.

I see that there is a special [Lexical](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.Lexical) parser to serve the purpose. But why actually this parser for the tokenization? What is the point? Why is it more advantageous? What is the point for its `EOL` and `whitespace` methods? Is it anyhow related to `skipWhitespace` that I see in `RegexParsers`? Moreover, I cannot find any example of stacking the parser on top of the lexer. It seems to me that higher-level RegexParsers uses `Input`, which is a stream of characters. How can it be a stream of tokens?

Btw, is it possible to build position tracking (`line:col`) into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep1` inside a `RegexParsers` will call `skipWhitespace` between the things it parses - meaning that you're getting a `Seq` with two `a`s in it. This is as documented in [RegexParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers).

If you want to get `line:col` data, have your result type of your parse extend [Position](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.input.Position), and wrap the parser in a call to [positioned](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers@positioned[T<:scala.util.parsing.input.Positional](p:=>Parsers.this.Parser[T]):Parsers.this.Parser[T]):

```
object Parser extends RegexParsers {
  case class MyType(value: String) extends Positional
  val myType: Parser[MyType] = positioned { "typey" ^^ { MyType.apply } }
}
```